# Excel resolution of date / time on x-axis of column chart

Tags: excel, date, charts

I am plotting a scatter chart in excel, date/time on the x-axis. I wish to highlight areas dynamically using columns as a secondary chart type, but I can't find a way to get the column to occupy the correct time, only the date.

For example the data below produces 5 overlapping columns, centred on the midpoint of the date.In my wider data set I have 95 date/time points but only get 6 columns from it, as it only covers 6 days.

[image: Chart Data]

Comment: So increase the x-axis information.